# install cuda by conda，can not use it

Tags: software-installation, cuda

```
/home/dengjunli/miniconda3/envs/3DGS2/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lcudart: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command '/usr/bin/g++' failed with exit code 1
[end of output] 
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for diff-gaussian-rasterization
  Running setup.py clean for diff-gaussian-rasterization
Failed to build diff-gaussian-rasterization
ERROR: Could not build wheels for diff-gaussian-rasterization, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and CUDA are you running?  What does echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH produce?  Please include additional information in your original posting, not in comments.